# Can I patch my 1.9.2.0 Magento store with a patch for the format 1.9.2.4?

Tags: magento-1.9, patches

so my store is currently running now on 1.9.2.0 and I wanted to patch it. Now I'm seeing that the format for the last patch is 1.9.2.4. Now my question is: can I still use the patch for my store?

https://www.magentocommerce.com/download

Full Release - ver 1.9.2.4

Answer (score 1):

no, you need the patches for your specific version, 
see the release notes:
http://merch.docs.magento.com/ce/user_guide/magento/release-notes.html

and choose the patches for your version here:
https://www.magentocommerce.com/download

i think that you need the patches:
SUPEE-6482, SUPEE-6788, SUPEE-7405, SUPEE-7616, SUPEE-7405 v.1.1, SUPEE-7978, SUPEE-7822, SUPEE-7882